# How to get buffered logging with Golang logrus

Tags: go

I am working with `github.com/sirupsen/logrus` module and have a requirement that the logs I generate should be buffered(time stamp preserved). I'll also start a timer when the operation begins and various steps of the operation will keep logging to this buffer.

At the end, if the total time spent in the operation is more than some threshold, I'll log everything else just discard the buffer.

I am just trying to find out how to elegantly implement this with `logrus`.

I have tried something like this:

```
type BufferedLog struct {
  Message string
  Level   logrus.Level
  Time    time.Time
}

type BufferingFormatter struct {
  bufferMutex sync.Mutex
  buffer      []*BufferedLog
}

func (f *BufferingFormatter) Format(entry *logrus.Entry) ([]byte, error) {

  bl := &BufferedLog{
    Message: entry.Message,
    Level:   entry.Level,
    Time:    entry.Time,
  }

  f.buffer = append(f.buffer, bl)
  return nil, nil
}

func PrintBufferedLogs(buffer []*BufferedLog) {
  now := time.Now()
  for _, log := range buffer {
    if now.Sub(log.Time) >= 5 * time.Second {
        data, err := json.Marshal(log)
        if err != nil {
            logrus.Errorf("error marshaling log entry to JSON: %v", err)
            continue
        }
        logrus.Print(string(data))
    }
  }
}

func NewBufferingLogger() *logrus.Logger {
  logger := logrus.New()
  bufferingFormatter := &BufferingFormatter{buffer: make([]*BufferedLog, 0)}
  logger.Formatter = bufferingFormatter
  return logger
}
```

And this is my main():

```
func main() {
  logrus.SetLevel(logrus.DebugLevel)
  logrus.SetFormatter(&logrus.TextFormatter{
    FullTimestamp: true,
  })
  bufferingLogger := NewBufferingLogger()
  bufferingLogger.SetLevel(logrus.DebugLevel)

  // Log some messages using the custom bufferingLogger
  bufferingLogger.Info("This is an informational message.")
  bufferingLogger.Warn("This is a warning message.")
  bufferingLogger.Error("This is an error message.")
  bufferingLogger.Debug("This is a debug message.")
  time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
  PrintBufferedLogs(bufferingLogger.Formatter.(*BufferingFormatter).buffer) 
}
```

It generates this output:

```
INFO {"message":"This is an informational message.","level":"info","time":"2023-07-25T11:41:17.545041+05:30"} 
INFO {"message":"This is a warning message.","level":"warning","time":"2023-07-25T11:41:17.545056+05:30"} 
INFO {"message":"This is an error message.","level":"error","time":"2023-07-25T11:41:17.545059+05:30"} 
INFO {"message":"This is a debug message.","level":"debug","time":"2023-07-25T11:41:17.545061+05:30"}
```

There are still lingering `INFO` in the output and this is changing the global `logrus` behavior as well.

What I am trying to do is to have this buffered logging as a separate logger and keep global `logrus` the way it is.

This looks like an overkill. Any better ideas ?

Comment: you can use a custom logger and a custom formatter for the buffered logs, create a new logger instance and set a separate formatter for it

Comment: Yes, that's what I'll be trying next. Still learning :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @ekundayo-blessing-funminiyi 's answer I modified his code a bit to get this

```
var buflogger *BufferedLogger

type BufferedLog struct {
    Message     string          `json:"message"`
    Level       logrus.Level    `json:"level"`
    Time        time.Time       `json:"time"`
    TimeSpent   time.Time       `json:"time_spent,omitempty"`
}

type BufferingFormatter struct {
    bufferMutex sync.Mutex
    buffer []*BufferedLog
}

func init() {
    logrus.SetLevel(logrus.DebugLevel)
    logrus.SetFormatter(&logrus.JSONFormatter{})
    once := sync.Once{}
    once.Do(func() {
        buflogger = NewBufferingLogger()
    })
}

func (f *BufferingFormatter) Format(entry *logrus.Entry) ([]byte, error) 
{
    f.bufferMutex.Lock()
    defer f.bufferMutex.Unlock()

    bl := &BufferedLog{
        Message: entry.Message,
        Level:   entry.Level,
        Time:    entry.Time.UTC(),
    }

    f.buffer = append(f.buffer, bl)
    return nil, nil
}

func (f *BufferingFormatter)PrintBufferedLogs() {
    f.bufferMutex.Lock()
    defer f.bufferMutex.Unlock()

    dumpAll := false
    now := time.Now()
    for _, log := range f.buffer {
        if dumpAll || (now.Sub(log.Time) >= 5*time.Minute) {
            dumpAll = true
            logrus.WithTime(log.Time).Log(log.Level, log.Message)
        }
    }

    // Flush the buffer to avoid memory leaks
    f.buffer = nil
}

func NewBufferingLogger() *BufferedLogger {
    if buflogger != nil {
        return buflogger
    }

    bufferingFormatter := &BufferingFormatter{buffer: make([]*BufferedLog, 0)}
    logger := logrus.New()
    logger.Level = logrus.DebugLevel
    logger.Formatter = bufferingFormatter
    buflogger =  &BufferedLogger{
        Logger:             logger,
        bufferingFormatter: bufferingFormatter,
    }
    return buflogger
}

type BufferedLogger struct {
    *logrus.Logger
    bufferingFormatter *BufferingFormatter
}

func (bl *BufferedLogger) PrintBufferedLogs() {
    bl.bufferingFormatter.PrintBufferedLogs()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your approach looks correct but a few points are missing.

**Independent Loggers**: Instead of changing global logrus logger, you can create a new logger instance using `logrus.New()`. Each instance of logrus Logger is independent and doesn't interfere with each other. Therefore, you can create a separate logger with a buffering formatter that won't impact the global logger.

**Printing Buffer Logs:** You can utilise a separate method to flush out logs after some operations are completed. This method should scan the buffered logs, and log them with your original (global) logger.

**Using Correct Level:** You should log the buffered logs with the correct level they were logged with. In your code, you used `logrus.Print()`, which doesn't respect the level of logs.

**Clear Buffer:** After printing buffered logs, you should clear the buffer to prevent duplicated logs in the next flush.

The updated code will be similar to this

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "time"

    "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
)

type MyFormatter struct {
}

func (f *MyFormatter) Format(entry *logrus.Entry) ([]byte, error) {
    b := &bytes.Buffer{}
    fmt.Fprintf(b, "{\"Level\":\"%s\",\"Time\":\"%s\",\"Message\":\"%s\"}\n", entry.Level, entry.Time.Format(time.RFC3339), entry.Message)
    return b.Bytes(), nil
}

type BufferedLog struct {
    Message string
    Level   logrus.Level
    Time    time.Time
}

func NewBufferingLogger() *logrus.Logger {
    logger := logrus.New()
    logger.Formatter = new(MyFormatter)
    logger.Level = logrus.DebugLevel
    return logger
}

func main() {
    bufferingLogger := NewBufferingLogger()

    // Log some messages using the custom bufferingLogger
    bufferingLogger.Info("This is an informational message.")
    bufferingLogger.Warn("This is a warning message.")
    bufferingLogger.Error("This is an error message.")
    bufferingLogger.Debug("This is a debug message.")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In my case, I am generating logs in `JSON` format which contains the log level.

Comment: You are welcome. I have updated the code to use the JSON format

Comment: This produces an output like this: `{"Level":"info","Message":"This is an informational message.","Time":"2023-07-25T12:45:29.887661+05:30","level":"info","msg":"","time":"2023-07-25T12:45:34+05:30"}`

Comment: I have updated it now you should have `{"Level":"info","Time":"2009-11-10T23:00:00Z","Message":"This is an informational message."}
`

Comment: I tested the code on Go Playground and it works when using `logger.SetLevel(logrus.DebugLevel)` in the updated code.

Comment: Yes, I removed my comment. I guess I am doing some mistake. Thanks for taking time to write and test the code. Much appreciated

Comment: But the latest code prints the messages immediately. I want to print only if the overall time crosses threshold